# error in running exe file after changing .py to .exe

Tags: python, opencv

I have changed my python code to an .exe file using pyinstaller and anaconda. In my python script ("untitled.py") I import opencv which I have already installed from source using cmake. After creating exe file I run untitled.exe in cmd windows. However, I get the following error:

> File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
> File "cv2_*init*_.py", line 96, in 
> File "cv2_*init*_.py", line 58, in bootstrap
> File "cv2_*init*_.py", line 56, in load_first_config
> ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation.

There is config.py in OpenCV folder, but it cannot be found. I tried this:

```
pyinstaller -F  --hidden-import ‘OpenCV’ untitled.py
```

But still does not work. I wanted to ask how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search of the error message reveals two issues describing the issue and potential solutions.

[One of the issues is in the pyinstaller repo](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4564), and suggests adding the cv2 path to the pyinstaller invocation:

```
pyinstaller --onefile sample.py --paths "/root/opencv-4.3.0/release/lib/python3/cv2"
```

You can get the actual path by running a simple python program:

```
import cv2
print(cv2.__file__)
```

[The other issue is in the opencv repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14064) and may apply especially if you compiled opencv yourself.

**UPDATE:** with respect to the error `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2`, [according to the FAQ](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/), you should install the [Visual Studio C++ redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got the actual path, which is "C:/Users/simin/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/cv2\python-3.8\cv2.cp38-win_amd64.pyd", then I used the following command: 
`pyinstaller --onefile untitled3.py --paths "C:/Users/simin/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/cv2" `. However, I still get the same error

Comment: Another option is the upgrade suggested in [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57769583/674487).

Comment: Thank you. I could solve the issue by using
` pyinstaller --onefile untitled3.py --paths "C:\Users\simin\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\cv2\python-3.8" `. 
However, I get another error: 
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: I updated the answer with the information regarding this new problem.

Comment: Thanks. everything is fine when I use opendcv in python editors or for running yolov3 from darknet repository. However, this error appears when trying to change .py to .exe. By the way I have installed opencv from source not using pip, and have visual studio c++ redistributable